# Screen resolution. Full screen - perfect. Normal screen - not perfect

Tags: css, browser, resolution

I'm creating a circle-like website which needs to be centered in the middle. The background consists out of a circle lining around the center image. Whenever I view my site in fullscreen (F11 shortcut) it is perfectly centered, no matter the resolution of my screen.

If I view my site without being in full screen, the resolution of my screen adjusts the background a little making it not perfectly centered.

For my background I have this as code:

```
* { 
padding:0; margin:0; 
}

html, body {
    height:100%; 
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    background-color: #1a1207;
    /* add font here */
    color: white;
}

body{
    background-image:url('../img/background.jpg');
    background-position: left;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-attachment: scroll;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-position: fixed;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    background-size: cover;
}
```

Is there any way to resolve this?

Answer (score 1):

Can't see the rest of the code but if you want the background to be centered don't you want it to set it up as:

```
body{
    background-position: center;
}
```

The way it is now, the background is properly centered for only one resolution, because it is aligned to the left.

Comment: Doesn't this automaticly make it: center center (thus centering?)

Comment: Isn't that what you want? or maybe you need something like: background-position:center top;

Comment: Ah yes, I thought I had this (was in an earlier version). The problem remains though.